# ATG Rest full API addItemToOrder is not working

Tags: atg, atg-droplet

I am working on ATG Web-commerce REST Full API, addItemToOrder is not working.
This is the Error:

```
{
  "formError": true,
  "formExceptions": [
    {
      "localizedMessage": "Unable to process the request currently. Please try again after some time",
      "errorCode": "atg.droplet.DropletException"
    }
  ],
  "concurrentUpdate": false
}
```

http://IP:Port/rest/model/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierActor/addItemToOrder

> I have checked the server log file, Null pointer exception is showing.

```
/atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-143/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler   ---     java.lang.NullPointerException
**** Error      /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-143/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler           at atg.siebel.catalog.SiebelCatalogTools.updateQuoteWithProfileDetails(SiebelCatalogTools.java:3681)
  /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-143/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler           at atg.siebel.catalog.SiebelCatalogTools.checkProductEligibility(SiebelCatalogTools.java:3384)
  /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-143/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler           at atg.siebel.validation.SiebelValidator.validateProductEligibility(SiebelValidator.java:141)
  /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-143/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler           at atg.siebel.order.purchase.SiebelCartModifierFormHandler.preAddItemToOrder(SiebelCartModifierFormHandler.java:569)
  /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-143/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler           at atg.commerce.order.purchase.CartModifierFormHandler.handleAddItemToOrder(CartModifierFormHandler.java:3035)
  /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-143/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-143/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-143/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-143/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler           at java.lang.reflect.Method.in
```

(there are more lines of error Unable to post here),
Would it be because of product sync issue? or sku's issue..?

Please help

Comment: Care to add the `NPE` in your question? Otherwise the answer to your problem is, you get an error due to an `NPE`.

Comment: what do you mean by NPE, I tried tagging to ATG web-commerce REST Full API I couldn't find out in the list Please advise,

Comment: I am seriously stuck on this issue, any hope ?

Comment: `NPE` is short for `NullPointerException`. Please add the Exception to your question because there isn't enough info here for us to help you.

Comment: Edited and published, there were more error, I could not able to post all error as it is long file.

Comment: You need to add at least the first 10 lines of the error in order for it to be useful.

Comment: Updated 10 Error, Please review and advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still a bit difficult to work out exactly where the error is but considering that you are calling the `updateQuoteWithProfileDetails(Quote,RepositoryItem)` method and in the calling method there is a `null` check on the `RepositoryItem` (profile) and `Quote` is `new`, then the only line that could end up with a `NullPointerException` in the calling code is:

```
parentOrganizationOfProfile = (RepositoryItem) profile.getPropertyValue(getProfilePropertyParentOrganization());
```

Which means that the `ProfileParentOrganisation` value on the `profile` `RepositoryItem` is `null`.

The rest of the code in that method (according to the source provided by ATG in the reference application) all provide `null` checks.

Comment: I am using ATG Restful API,  Bit confused as I am new the domain. AddtoCart method is not related to CRM right?, so I dont need to check CRM log. Hoping addtoCart doesnot need to communicate to CRM.

Comment: I am calling addItemToOrder API, not aware of inner methods. Please Advise.

Comment: As I said in my answer, your `ProfileParentOrganisation` of the `profile` you are trying to use is `null`. Check your data.

Comment: hi, there was no progress, As I am new to ATG I am feeling difficulty and tried multiple ways to understand the answer. I have some query about the same, 

1.> Is this addItemToOrder is calling any Siebel web services? 
2.> Or this call is within the ATG?
3.> If its calling Siebel service, Please explain about the web service

Comment: I've never worked with the Siebel integration but what I can say is that your problem is in your data in the ATG instance. You probably only need to setup a `ProfileParentOrganisation` on the user you are trying to use for the query. This is likely done via the BCC.

Comment: I haven't used the ACC in years but I believe it will work.

Comment: tried creating Organizations and added user to that organization, But now the error got changed.**Unsupported Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8 Supported ones are: [text/xml]**, tried changing the content-type to supported one, after this step **Session mismatch** error, Other API's are working fine with the content-type : application/json. please advise.

Comment: That sounds like a new error which has a new stack trace which probably should be a new question.

Comment: Added new Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38637190/working-with-atg-rest-full-api-additemtoorder-error -- Please check and advise.