# Working with ATG Rest full API addItemToOrder ERROR

Tags: atg, atg-droplet

As advised from the question:[ATG Rest full API addItemToOrder is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38183721/atg-rest-full-api-additemtoorder-is-not-working)

I have created an organization and added the user in it null pointer exeption got cleared but,Now new error started coming up below are the server error

```
**** debug  Fri Jul 22 09:30:45 EDT 2016    1469194245004   /atg/siebel/integration/LogMessageHandler   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
**** debug  Fri Jul 22 09:30:45 EDT 2016    1469194245004   /atg/siebel/integration/LogMessageHandler   <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
**** debug  Fri Jul 22 09:30:45 EDT 2016    1469194245004   /atg/siebel/integration/LogMessageHandler     <S:Header>
**** debug  Fri Jul 22 09:30:45 EDT 2016    1469194245004   /atg/siebel/integration/LogMessageHandler       <sbh:ServerDetermine xmlns:sbh="http://siebel.com/webservices">SessionType</sbh:ServerDetermine>
**** debug  Fri Jul 22 09:30:45 EDT 2016    1469194245004   /atg/siebel/integration/LogMessageHandler       <sbh:LangCode xmlns:sbh="http://siebel.com/webservices">ENU</sbh:LangCode>
**** debug  Fri Jul 22 09:30:45 EDT 2016    1469194245004   /atg/siebel/integration/LogMessageHandler       <sbh:Locale xmlns:sbh="http://siebel.com/webservices">ENU</sbh:Locale>
**** debug  Fri Jul 22 09:30:45 EDT 2016    1469194245004   /atg/siebel/integration/LogMessageHandler       <sbh:UsernameToken xmlns:sbh="http://siebel.com/webservices">SADMIN</sbh:UsernameToken>
**** debug  Fri Jul 22 09:30:45 EDT 2016    1469194245004   /atg/siebel/integration/LogMessageHandler       <sbh:PasswordText xmlns:sbh="http://siebel.com/webservices">SADMIN</sbh:PasswordText>
**** debug  Fri Jul 22 09:30:45 EDT 2016    1469194245004   /atg/siebel/integration/LogMessageHandler     </S:Header>
**** debug  Fri Jul 22 09:30:45 EDT 2016    1469194245004   /atg/siebel/integration/LogMessageHandler     <S:Body>
**** debug  Fri Jul 22 09:30:45 EDT 2016    1469194245004   /atg/siebel/integration/LogMessageHandler       <ns2:CheckQuoteEligibilityCompatibility_Input xmlns="http://siebel.com/OrderManagement/Quote/Data" xmlns:ns2="http://siebel.com/OrderManagement/Quote/PSP" xmlns:ns3="http://siebel.com/OrderManagement/Quote/Data/ProjectedAsset">
**** debug  Fri Jul 22 09:30:45 EDT 2016    1469194245004   /atg/siebel/integration/LogMessageHandler         <ns2:PickMode>Pre-Pick</ns2:PickMode>
**** debug  Fri Jul 22 09:30:45 EDT 2016    1469194245004   /atg/siebel/integration/LogMessageHandler         <ns3:ListOfAsset/>
**** debug  Fri Jul 22 09:30:45 EDT 2016    1469194245004   /atg/siebel/integration/LogMessageHandler         <ns2:PSPMode>External PDS Quote</ns2:PSPMode>
**** debug  Fri Jul 22 09:30:45 EDT 2016    1469194245004   /atg/siebel/integration/LogMessageHandler         <ListOfQuote>
**** debug  Fri Jul 22 09:30:45 EDT 2016    1469194245004   /atg/siebel/integration/LogMessageHandler           <Quote>
**** debug  Fri Jul 22 09:30:45 EDT 2016    1469194245004   /atg/siebel/integration/LogMessageHandler             <Id>144844588</Id>
**** debug  Fri Jul 22 09:30:45 EDT 2016    1469194245004   /atg/siebel/integration/LogMessageHandler             <ListOfQuoteItem>
**** debug  Fri Jul 22 09:30:45 EDT 2016    1469194245004   /atg/siebel/integration/LogMessageHandler             <QuoteItem>
**** debug  Fri Jul 22 09:30:45 EDT 2016    1469194245004   /atg/siebel/integration/LogMessageHandler             <InclusiveEligibilityFlag>N</InclusiveEligibilityFlag>
**** debug  Fri Jul 22 09:30:45 EDT 2016    1469194245004   /atg/siebel/integration/LogMessageHandler             <Id>290257599</Id>
**** debug  Fri Jul 22 09:30:45 EDT 2016    1469194245004   /atg/siebel/integration/LogMessageHandler             <ProductId>1-18CKW</ProductId>
**** debug  Fri Jul 22 09:30:45 EDT 2016    1469194245004   /atg/siebel/integration/LogMessageHandler             </QuoteItem>
**** debug  Fri Jul 22 09:30:45 EDT 2016    1469194245004   /atg/siebel/integration/LogMessageHandler             </ListOfQuoteItem>
**** debug  Fri Jul 22 09:30:45 EDT 2016    1469194245004   /atg/siebel/integration/LogMessageHandler           </Quote>
**** debug  Fri Jul 22 09:30:45 EDT 2016    1469194245004   /atg/siebel/integration/LogMessageHandler         </ListOfQuote>
**** debug  Fri Jul 22 09:30:45 EDT 2016    1469194245004   /atg/siebel/integration/LogMessageHandler       </ns2:CheckQuoteEligibilityCompatibility_Input>
**** debug  Fri Jul 22 09:30:45 EDT 2016    1469194245004   /atg/siebel/integration/LogMessageHandler     </S:Body>
**** debug  Fri Jul 22 09:30:45 EDT 2016    1469194245004   /atg/siebel/integration/LogMessageHandler   </S:Envelope>
**** debug  Fri Jul 22 09:30:45 EDT 2016    1469194245004   /atg/siebel/integration/LogMessageHandler   
**** Error  Fri Jul 22 09:30:48 EDT 2016    1469194248987   /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-2/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler --- com.sun.xml.ws.server.UnsupportedMediaException: Unsupported Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8 Supported ones are: [text/xml]
**** Error  Fri Jul 22 09:30:48 EDT 2016    1469194248987   /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-2/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler     at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:319)
**** Error  Fri Jul 22 09:30:48 EDT 2016    1469194248987   /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-2/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler     at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:151)
**** Error  Fri Jul 22 09:30:48 EDT 2016    1469194248987   /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-2/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler     at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.decode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:290)
**** Error  Fri Jul 22 09:30:48 EDT 2016    1469194248987   /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-2/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler     at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:277)
**** Error  Fri Jul 22 09:30:48 EDT 2016    1469194248987   /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-2/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler     at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:124)
**** Error  Fri Jul 22 09:30:48 EDT 2016    1469194248987   /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-2/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler     at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:118)
**** Error  Fri Jul 22 09:30:48 EDT 2016    1469194248987   /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-2/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler     at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:866)
**** Error  Fri Jul 22 09:30:48 EDT 2016    1469194248987   /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-2/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler     at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:815)
**** Error  Fri Jul 22 09:30:48 EDT 2016    1469194248987   /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-2/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler     at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:778)
**** Error  Fri Jul 22 09:30:48 EDT 2016    1469194248987   /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-2/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler     at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:680)
**** Error  Fri Jul 22 09:30:48 EDT 2016    1469194248987   /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-2/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler     at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:272)
**** Error  Fri Jul 22 09:30:48 EDT 2016    1469194248987   /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-2/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler     at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:153)
**** Error  Fri Jul 22 09:30:48 EDT 2016    1469194248987   /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-2/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler     at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:115)
**** Error  Fri Jul 22 09:30:48 EDT 2016    1469194248987   /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-2/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler     at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:95)
**** Error  Fri Jul 22 09:30:48 EDT 2016    1469194248987   /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-2/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler     at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:136)
**** Error  Fri Jul 22 09:30:48 EDT 2016    1469194248987   /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-2/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy90.checkQuoteEligibilityCompatibility(Unknown Source)
**** Error  Fri Jul 22 09:30:48 EDT 2016    1469194248987   /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-2/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
**** Error  Fri Jul 22 09:30:48 EDT 2016    1469194248987   /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-2/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
**** Error  Fri Jul 22 09:30:48 EDT 2016    1469194248987   /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-2/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
**** Error  Fri Jul 22 09:30:48 EDT 2016    1469194248987   /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-2/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
**** Error  Fri Jul 22 09:30:48 EDT 2016    1469194248987   /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-2/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler     at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.ClientInstanceInvocationHandler.invoke(ClientInstanceInvocationHandler.java:84)
**** Error  Fri Jul 22 09:30:48 EDT 2016    1469194248987   /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-2/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy91.checkQuoteEligibilityCompatibility(Unknown Source)
**** Error  Fri Jul 22 09:30:48 EDT 2016    1469194248987   /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-2/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler     at atg.siebel.catalog.SiebelCatalogTools.callEligibilityCompatabilityWebService(SiebelCatalogTools.java:3649)
**** Error  Fri Jul 22 09:30:48 EDT 2016    1469194248987   /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-2/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler     at atg.siebel.catalog.SiebelCatalogTools.checkProductEligibility(SiebelCatalogTools.java:3465)
**** Error  Fri Jul 22 09:30:48 EDT 2016    1469194248987   /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-2/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler     at atg.siebel.validation.SiebelValidator.validateProductEligibility(SiebelValidator.java:149)
**** Error  Fri Jul 22 09:30:48 EDT 2016    1469194248987   /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-2/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler     at atg.siebel.order.purchase.SiebelCartModifierFormHandler.preAddItemToOrder(SiebelCartModifierFormHandler.java:569)
**** Error  Fri Jul 22 09:30:48 EDT 2016    1469194248987   /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-2/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler     at atg.commerce.order.purchase.CartModifierFormHandler.handleAddItemToOrder(CartModifierFormHandler.java:3035)
```

**Work Flow**

***Add To cart [POST method]***

> Content-type:application/json

http://IP:PORT/rest/model/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierActor/addItemToOrder

```
Input:
{
     "_dynSessConf":"2956331551008735411",
     "catalogRefIds" : "sku70157",
     "productId": "1-18CKW",
     "quantity":1
}

Output:
{
  "formError": true,
  "formExceptions": [
    {
      "localizedMessage": "Unable to process the request currently. Please try again after some time",
      "errorCode": "atg.droplet.DropletException"
    }
  ],
  "concurrentUpdate": false
}
```

***Server Log***

```
**** Error  Fri Jul 22 09:30:48 EDT 2016    1469194248987   /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-2/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler --- com.sun.xml.ws.server.UnsupportedMediaException: Unsupported Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8 Supported ones are: [text/xml]
```

***Add To cart [POST method]***

> Content-type:text/xml

http://IP:PORT/rest/model/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierActor/addItemToOrder

```
Input:
{
     "_dynSessConf":"2956331551008735411",
     "catalogRefIds" : "sku70157",
     "productId": "1-18CKW",
     "quantity":1
}

Output:
Your session expired due to inactivity.
```

***Server Log***

```
**** Warning    Fri Jul 22 09:39:13 EDT 2016    1469194753357   /atg/dynamo/servlet/pagecompile/DAFDropletEventServlet  Missing session confirmation number: Request URI: /rest/model/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierActor/addItemToOrder
```

Answer (score 1):

The error that you are getting is not because your request is using the incorrect `Content-Type` but rather that the response you are getting back from the endpoint of your `SOAP` call is returning an `HTML` response (most likely a `404` error response). You will need to confirm that the endpoint you are trying to connect to is actually valid using some tool like `SOAPUI` and passing the `SoapEnvelope` you generated in the debug statement to the endpoint and confirm the response.

Comment: I somewhat agree with your assessment; to me it looks like whatever SOAP client that atg.siebel.catalog.SiebelCatalogTools is using, that it is not sending the correct Content-Type header. It is hard to diagnose without knowing more about how the SOAP client was generated.